# Three sacks with balls weighing $9,10$ and $11$ gram.

Tags: inequality

A man has three bags filled with balls. One bag contains balls weighing $9$ grams, the second bag contains balls weighing $10$ grams and the third bag contains balls weighing $11$ grams. The man got confused and does not know which bag contains which balls. But in each bag all the balls weigh the same. He has an old-fashioned scale that is about to break. This means that he can only weigh once with it. How does the man find out which ball weighs what?

Comment: This is probably better posed on [Puzzling.SE](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, but I would like to get the principle out of it. I have some attempts but I still fail ...

Comment: Then please add your attempts to your question and hopefully someone will be able to help you understand where you are going wrong

Comment: Does the scale give you the exact weight you put on it, or is it a two side balance scale?

Comment: Then the problem is impossible. There are only three outcomes, but there are six possibilities for the bags. Not enough comparisons.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but could you distinguish by the amount of chosen balls which is which? Or can I prove, that this is impossible instead?

Comment: @JohnSmith: Parcly Taxel proved that it's impossible in the preceding comment. From the one weighing you will get one of three possible results. It doesn't matter how many balls you choose or where you choose them from; not matter what you weigh, in the end you need to infer the bag identities from the three possible results, and that's impossible since there are six possible permutations of the bags.

Comment: @joriki Funnily enough, today's CS3230 (Design and Analysis of Algorithms, National University of Singapore) lecture talked about the decision tree model and the $\Omega(n\log n)$ lower bound for comparison sorting. I was obviously still warm with the idea of decision trees from there!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. My mistake was to understand it as a problem of a balance scale. This is indeed unsolvable. The solution for a scale returning a number is posted below.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR** It is impossible to identify the weights of all three balls from a single weigh

---

It is possible to identify the weight of the balls in one of the bags by picking a bag at random and putting two balls from this bag on one side of the scales and then putting one ball from each of the other two bags onto the other side of the scales.

It is pretty obvious to see that there are $3$ possibilities for the scales in this situation

```
Side 1       Side 2       Outcome
---------------------------------------------
9,9          10,11        tips towards side 2
10,10        9,11         balanced
11,11        9,10         tips towards side 1
```

We can use this table to identify the weight of the balls on side 1 however we do not have a way to distinguish between the two balls on side 2 without doing a second weigh (unless the man is able to tell by holding one in each hand which is heavier, which would be pretty hard with only 2 grams in it!)

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

The question has an answer and I came up with it. The correct answer is taking the balls $a,b,c$ in the following way, while $n$ is the number of sacks:
$$
(1 \cdot a + n \cdot b + n^2 \cdot c) - (1+n+n^2) \cdot \min(\{9,10,11\}) = s.
$$
This gives a number to be interpreted in the polyadic basis of the amount of sacks. So we convert the outcome $(s)_{10} = (s')_3$. The digits tell us, which ball had which weight.

For example:
$$
(1\cdot 11 + 3 \cdot 10 + 9 \cdot 9) - 117 = (12)_3\\
(1\cdot 10 + 3 \cdot 11 + 9 \cdot 9) - 117 = (21)_3\\
(1 \cdot 9 + 3 \cdot 10 + 9 \cdot 11)- 117 = (210)_3
$$

This solution is unique and works also, if the sacks could have all the same weights or some permutation of the given possible weights.

Comment: If the scale is a balance scale, you can't get a number $s$ out of the outcome. You just learn that one side is heavier or lighter (or that they balance).

Comment: Well, that was in fact my misunderstanding about the puzzle. I apologize for that.